# How to override update (put) method in loopback js

Tags: loopbackjs

Based on loopback documentations, We can override remote methods.I want to override `PUT : /products/{id}` requests.

I try this:

```
module.exports = function (product) {
    product.save = function(data,callback){
        callback();
    }
};
```

I try it with : `update` , `updateAttributes` , `upsert` and all related methods but still not working...

Although overriding `create` method working but `update` no!

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `product.prototype` can trigger `put` requests like this :

```
product.prototype.updateAttributes = function (data,callback) {
    console.log('updateAttributes');
    callback();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the API end point, you can use the following,

```
Product.disableRemoteMethod('update', true)
Product.disableRemoteMethod('updateAttributes', true)
Product.disableRemoteMethod('upsert', true)
```

Documentation Link - https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST#ExposingmodelsoverREST-Exposingandhidingmodels,methods,andendpoints